# Best way to embed without affecting on Loading speed

Tags: javascript, html

How to reduce loading time caused by iframe embed YouTube video?

Answer (score 3):

## Method 1

You could try lazy-loading the embedded video: loading it once they've scrolled down enough to actually see the video OR only loading the video once play has been clicked. This method is of course only useful when the embedded video is lower on your page. [Here's a great guide on how to lazy load embedded YouTube videos.](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-lazy-load-embedded-youtube-videos--cms-26743)

## Method 2

Load the entire page. Once loaded, generate the video embed code using Javascript.
jQuery example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Page is fully loaded, generate the iframe and set attributes
     var aFrame = $('<iframe>');

     $(aFrame).attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/EU7PRmCpx-0');
     $(aFrame).attr('width', '560');
     $(aFrame).attr('height', '315');

     // iframe element is created, append it to the body (or another element)
     $('body').append(aFrame);
});
```

Comment: Good answer. Can you add a working example?

Comment: @lumio I added an example for the first method and expanded my example for method 2.